# Is it possible to run NetBeans and BlueJ on Mac OS X without incompatibility?

Tags: macos, netbeans, compatibility, java

I would like to play around with the Java SE version of NetBeans on Mac, however I need to still have a running copy of BlueJ on my Mac for a school class. Is it possible to run the "JDK-only" BlueJ and the "Java SE" NetBeans together in harmony?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it and see. My Mac maintains several versions of Java although I don't really know what gets used where.

It might be worth looking at this FAQ: http://www.bluej.org/help/faq.html#macjava5

Comment: I've just installed BlueJ on my 10.5 Mac and I also have Netbeans running. There don't seem to be any problems.